# Are there any commentaries in the pali cannon on The Iddhipāda-Vibhaṅga Sutta -- An Analysis Of The Bases Of Power (SN 51:20)

Tags: pali-canon, pali, commentary

Are there any commentaries in the pali cannon on The Iddhipāda-Vibhaṅga Sutta -- An Analysis Of The Bases Of Power (SN 51:20). And in general, what are some sources for the commentaries, obviously in pali but also in english. (If only in pali, a preference to be able to locate and navigate without knowing much pali.)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a traditional Pali commentary on this yet but here is a modern commentary by [Piya Tan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piya_Tan): [Iddhipada Vibhanga Sutta (SN 51.20)](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/28.14-Iddhipada-Vibhanga-S-s51.20-piya.pdf).

Piya Tan usually refers to multiple sources including the traditional commentaries, to write his own.

Answer (score 1):

Abhidhamma [Iddhipada Vibhanga](https://suttacentral.net/vb9/en/thittila?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

[Visuddhimagga](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf) (search under 'roads to power')

Malaysian scholar Piya Tan usually has references to Commentaries: [Iddhi,pāda Vibhanga Sutta](https://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/28.14-Iddhipada-Vibhanga-S-s51.20-piya.pdf)